# jQuery Not return result if not include alert in the script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Jquery ajax function to get date value to count down object. 
That code work correctly. when parsing date to count down its working only insert alert before set date to the count down method.

this is script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            var austDay = new Date();
            var currDay = new Date();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Service/Utility/GetDownDate',
                success: function (data) {
                    austDay = new Date(parseInt(data.newDate.substr(6)));
                    //alert(austDay);
                }
            });

            austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear(), 1 - 1, 26);
            alert(austDay);

            $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: austDay });
            $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
        });
    </script>
```

pls help me.
Thanks,

Comment: any error in console?, i think you should to declare `austDay` outside of document.ready function.

Answer (score 2):

Since ajax is asynchronous, you need to use the success event to get the data. Try like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        var austDay = new Date();
        var currDay = new Date();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Service/Utility/GetDownDate',
            success: function (data) {
                austDay = new Date(parseInt(data.newDate.substr(6)));
                //alert(austDay);
                austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear(), 1 - 1, 26);
               $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: austDay });
                $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Actually its not alert() doing the magic. If you put an alert, the success event will happen with in less timespan, before the user clicks ok button.

Comment: `success:` is deprecated and you should use `.done` instead. See https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @DHS: The `success` option to `ajax` (what Anoop used above) is not deprecated. The `success` *method* on the `jqXHR` object (what `ajax` *returns*) is deprecated, in favor of the `Promise` methods that replace it.

Comment: No machan count down is working. only that alert problem is here. count down is date type count down.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    var austDay = new Date();
    var currDay = new Date();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/Service/Utility/GetDownDate',
        success: function (data) {
            austDay = new Date(parseInt(data.newDate.substr(6)));
            austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear(), 1 - 1, 26);

            $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: austDay });
            $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
        }
});
```

**Reason**

you are calling ajax, it work asynchronous,So your `countdown()` is executed before your ajax complete.
When you put alert it get time to complete ajax call till you click ok button then after that `countdown()` is executed

Comment: Looks like Anoop finished the race first.

Comment: alert(data.newDate.substr(6)) see what you get in success